# Determine the values of $x$ & $y$, such that the matrix is stochastic

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix shows the changes between three groups of people: D, E, F

2 of the values are unknown and are shown as $x$ and $y$

The matrix is $3\times3$

Does anyone know what my first step should be?

Comment: Please give more information about the matrix, then answers could be more precise.

Comment: Pretty odd question...but the matrix's entries must be  between zero and one and the sum of each of its columns must be one. (There is also left and right etochastic...)

Comment: First row of matrix= .75 .3  .2

Comment: Second= .15  .7  x

Comment: Third = y  0  .60

Comment: Include the information in your original post, otherwise be prepared for the incoming downvotes  (not from me) :)

Answer (score 0):

As I know the sum of the rows has to be one, but here it seem to be the other way, so:
$$0.75 + 0.15 + y = 1 \Rightarrow y = ?$$
Calculate $x$ analogue.